# Adding new HighChart Series

Tags: arrays, highcharts, live, series

At this code javascrip give an error

```
$.each(JSON, function(i, array) {                        
    chart.series[i].name = array.teamName;
    chart.series[i].setData(array.teamPower, true);
});
```

I must define the chart.series[i] because it say "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"
but i can't find a way in order to do this.

Because it fonction runs with requestData so it came after chart determine with options

```
function showGraph() {  
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(option);       
}
```

---

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'graphicShow',
    type: 'spline',
    events: {
        load: requestData
    }
}
```

---

...in option...

```
title: {
    text: 'Power %'
},
series: []
```

...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to looka at the "Methods and Properties" part of the API. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart (There is an jsFiddle on the documentation page as well).

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
chart.addSeries({                        
    name: array.teamName,
    data: array.teamPowher
});
```

If you are going to add several series you should set the `redraw` flag to false and then call redraw manually after as that will be much faster.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
chart.addSeries({                        
    name: array.teamName,
    data: array.teamPower
}, false);
chart.addSeries({                        
    name: array.teamName,
    data: array.teamPower
}, false);
chart.redraw();
```

Comment: Is there a way to reference the series by name, or is it just there for tooltips etc?

Comment: You can use the Chart.get function, see here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get(). Please note the differance between "name" and "id".

Comment: does this work any differently now with `v6+`? I am getting errors in TS with this.

Answer (score 0):

You too can specify as second option of `addSeries` a boolean value, that indicates if it redraws or not