# Can the lines in Highcharts appear one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, line

I have multiple lines in a Highcharts graph, and would like to make them appear one after another, and not all at the same time. Is that possible? I have [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/qu553bym/2/).

Perhaps one approach would be to display first no line at all (how?), and then make them appear in an additional function like:

```
    function(chart)
    { 
        chart.series[0].drawLine({lineWidth: 1}),
        chart.series[1].drawLine({lineWidth: 1}),
        chart.series[2].drawLine({lineWidth: 1});
    });
```

where I have however no idea to make them appear... Any tipp for me? Thanks so much!

Comment: You can [add series to an existing chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166561/adding-new-highchart-series) one by one, with a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries) one by one, i.e in setTimeout function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
              chart.addSeries({
                    data: [1,2,3]
              });

              setTimeout(function(){
                chart.addSeries({
                      data: [2,3,4]
                });
              },1000);
},1000);
```

Simple demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/sdpxahcq/